# How to install 'requests' module in python on windows 10

Tags: python, pip

I am a beginner learning Python. I think this should have been a simple task. I am trying to install 'requests' module in command prompt using pip. Python version is 3.11.4. Below is the output from the cmd.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests)
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.2.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (96 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 61.5/61.5 kB 164.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Downloading urllib3-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (123 kB)
     ----------------------- ---------------- 71.7/123.6 kB 7.4 kB/s eta 0:00:07
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 561, in read
    data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 527, in _fp_read
    return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 90, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 466, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1278, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1134, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 427, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 239, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 230, in _get_updated_criteria
    self._add_to_criteria(criteria, requirement, parent=candidate)
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
                ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 293, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 304, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 516, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 587, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 166, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 107, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 147, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 622, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 560, in read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received indicates a **timeout** while trying to download the package from the Python Package Index (PyPI). This issue could be due to a slow or unstable internet connection or temporary server issues. Here are a few suggestions to resolve the problem:

1. Check your internet connection: Make sure you have a stable internet connection and try running the installation command again.
2. Upgrade pip: Ensure you have the latest version of pip by running the following command:

   python -m pip install --upgrade pip
3. Use a different package index mirror: PyPI has multiple mirrors worldwide. You can try using a different mirror by adding the --index-url option to the installation command. For example:

   pip install requests --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/

I hope these suggestions help you resolve the timeout issue and successfully install the 'requests' module. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem solved. PIP didn't need to upgrade, it was the most recent version. Using the mirror solved the problem.